# How to load script when wsadmin shell is used

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal, ibm-was, wsadmin

A system administrator has created a Python script called globalScript. py.
What should the administrator do to ensure globalScript. py is loaded when the wsadmin shell is
used?

A.
Compile globalScript.py to a Java class in the bin directory.

B.
Invoke wsadmin with the argument-profileName globalScript.py.

C.
Modify the configureCustomProperty script to import globalScript. py.

D.
D. Set the script profiles in the wsadmin.properties file to load globalScript .py.

Comment: wsadmin.properties has this entry  #————————————————————————-
# The profiles property is a list of profiles to be run before
# running user commands, scripts, or an interactive shell.
# securityProcs is included here by default to make security
# configuration easier.
#————————————————————————-
com.ibm.ws.scripting.profiles=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/securityProcs.py;/

Comment: Yeah , i think wsadmin.properties is loaded every time we connect to wsadmin

Comment: @Nayeem You should just add your comment as an answer since answer "D" seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wsadmin.properties has this entry **com.ibm.ws.scripting.profiles** where we can add the scripting files to be loaded

So D should be the answer

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The profiles property is a list of profiles to be run before
# running user commands, scripts, or an interactive shell.
# securityProcs is included here by default to make security
# configuration easier.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.ibm.ws.scripting.profiles=/hosting/products/WebSphereD24/bin/securityProcs.jacl;/hosting/products/WebSphereD24/bin/LTPA_LDAPSecurityProcs.jacl
```